# Authorize net gateway process in android failed

Tags: android, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am working on payment process in my application. I am following the authorize.net [sample example](http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android/)
as per the steps I imported library and the code but when I am testing in test mode with account created I am getting error response. I tested it in emulator. In the guide they provide for help there is no notes for this error message about what is the real solution.

```
Error Code: 87
Error message: Transactions of this market type is not processed on this system.
```

Can anybody suggest on this ?

Comment: Does this help? http://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A597&actp=LIST

Comment: @ken the link already i have noticed but what they are saying is not clear......

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the account that you are using was created for Card Present (retail) transactions, but you are trying to integrate to the Card Not Present (e-commerce) APIs or vice versa.  Simply create and use a new sandbox account with the correct type.

You can read more about it [here](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/5-Most-Common-Errors/ba-p/35655).